# Can I have a firewall device between DD-WRT VPN and Wireless Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn, firewall, dd-wrt

I have a Sophos XG Firewall device and I want to use it with my DD-WRT router that will have OpenVPN running for a third-party VPN service. Can I have it set up as follows?

Modem --> DD-WRT Router with VPN --> Sophos Firewall Device --> Wireless Router --> Connected Devices

Essentially I want to be able to use the Firewall along with the VPN. Also, the Sophos device doesn't allow it to run third-party VPN services (besides site-site, ect...).

Comment: Have you thought about Sophos UTM instead, & drop the router down to pure modem mode?

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought about using UTM. I was hoping there would be a way to have the DD-WRT router work purely as a VPN and not as an AP.

Comment: tbh, i've not much experience with piling one behind the other. I built a home license [free for 50 seats, BYO computer + 2 NICs] UTM about 5 years ago & dumbed my router down to pure modem mode. The UTM build has done everything, ever since.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is pretty much what I want to do but with a VPN before the Firewall. How do your devices connect after the UTM? Is there an AP after the firewall?

Comment: Essentially, the UTM is in charge of everything. I have regular APs behind it, also dumbed-down & slaving to the UTM's DHCP etc [I can't afford Sophos 'smart' APs.] the UTM handles all comms, VPN etc. The router is totally pass-through.

Comment: @Tetsujin What does the connection path look like? Is it Modem-->Router-->UTM? or Model-->UTM-->Router? Or something else?

Comment: 'internal network' > UTM >  modem > 'the world'. UTM does it all.

Comment: @Tetsujin Does the UTM broadcast wireless AP? Or are your devices all wired?

Comment: Everything is wired to the UTM